# Relation between given points in a line

Tags: geometry, slope

Which formula can I use for getting the relationship given below, from the geometry described in the picture?

How can I relate these 2 points given?

$$k=R \left( \frac{\omega_c}{1-e^{-RTs/L}} \right)$$

Graph:

[image: graph]

Comment: I have replaced your second image by a written formula.

Comment: @JeanMarie which formula did you use?

Comment: `$k=R \left( \frac{\omega_c}{1-e^{-RTs/L}} \right)$`

Comment: Calculating the slope to be -1 from the two points did not lead to the result as presented in the equation.

Comment: Just saw that the scales on the aces are decibels and logarithmic, son the differences equal division, resulting in the formula